# Stack overflow? Interesting behaviour during very deep recursion

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

While I was making my assignment on BST, Linked Lists and AVL I noticed.. actually it is as in the title.

I believe it is somehow related to stack overflow, but could not find why it is happening.

### Creation of the BST and Linked list

[image: creation]

### Searching for all elements in Linked list and BST

[image: search]
And probably most interesting...

### Comparison of the height of BST and AVL

(based on array of unique random integers)
[image: avlbst]

On every graph something interesting begins around 33k elements.

Optimization O2 in MS Visual Studio 2019 Community.

Search function of Linked list is **not** recursive.

Memory for each "link" was allocated with "new" operator.

X axis ends on 40k elements because when it is about 43k then stack overflow error happens.

Do you know why does it happen? Actually, I'm curious what is happening. Looking forward to your answers! Stay healthy.

Here is some related code although it is not exactly the same, I can assure it works the same and it could be said some code was based on it.

```
struct tree {
        tree() {
        info = NULL;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
        }
        int info;
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
};

struct tree *insert(struct tree*& root, int x) {
    if(!root) {
        root= new tree;
        root->info = x;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
        return(root);
    }
    if(root->info > x)
         root->left = insert(root->left,x); else {
        if(root->info < x)
            root->right = insert(root->right,x);
    }
    return(root);
}

struct tree *search(struct tree*& root, int x) {
    struct tree *ptr;
    ptr=root;
    while(ptr) {
        if(x>ptr->info)
             ptr=ptr->right; else if(x<ptr->info)
             ptr=ptr->left; else
             return ptr;
    }

int bstHeight(tree*& tr) {
    if (tr == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    int lefth = bstHeight(tr->left);
    int righth = bstHeight(tr->right);

    if (lefth > righth) {
        return lefth + 1;
    } else {
        return righth + 1;
    }
}
```

AVL tree is a BST read inorder and then, array of the elements is inserted into tree object through bisection.

Comment: `new` does not allocate on the stack ...

Comment: @ChrisMM Some sources state that it is allocated on stack. Some other options I've found include free memory, "raw data", "it is just allocated, nothing more". I don't know whom should I trust hah

Comment: It uses dynamic memory, usually the heap space. Anyway, without seeing some relevant code, not sure anyone can help explain why at 33k you get that spike.

Comment: It's generally not possible for `new` to allocate memory from the stack, because due to the simple nature of the stack, stack allocations must always be freed in the exact opposite order that they were allocated in -- but allocations done via `new` may be freed in any order (or even never freed at all, if you forget to call `delete` on them).

OTOH note that local/automatic variables and function arguments are usually allocated on the stack.

Comment: You're probably hitting the limit of some cache such as the CPU's L2 cache.

Comment: @David_Schwartz Yeah, it could answer the question about the time spike, but what about the height? Those graphs are based on the lowest values I have got out of 5 repeats in a row.

Comment: I think the stack overflow is a symptom, probably of a bug in how you select elements. If you're using rand()` and an implementation like Windows in which `RAND_MAX` is 32767, then perhaps when you hit 32768 elements something goes badly wrong with the code which selects the next element to insert.

Comment: @rici I completely missed that! All indexes above 32768 in the so thought array of "randomly placed" unique numbers, are actually sorted. Sorry for not including that in the code above, but if I was to copy it here, it would be about ~370 lines. I will look for another way of drawing random numbers or use the following formula `int a = rand(); int b = rand(); a = a*b%size_of_array; swap(array[a],array[a*rand()%size_of_array]);`. I guess you have the idea how the array is mixed up. Thank you all for your help! Stay healthy.

Comment: That behavior isn't too unexpected. When your recursion starts jeopardizing stack space, there are probably stack management routines that try and keep thing from going awry. I'm sure what happens if that is the case would be implementation defined. I always just thought you recursed until things blew up, but never bothered to graph it. Would be nice to know what exactly accounts for that behavior.

Comment: You should clarify what you're graphing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spikes in time could be, and I am nearly sure they are, because of using up some cache of the CPU (L2 for example). Some leftover data was stored somewhere in slower memory.

The answer is thanks to @David_Schwartz

Spike in the height of the BST tree is actually my own fault. For the "array of unique random" integers I used array of already sorted unique items, then mixing them up by swapping elements with the `rand()` function. I have totally forgotten how devastating could it be if expected to random larger numbers.

Thanks @rici for pointing it out.

Comment: I'll be interested in seeing your new graphs. All of the increase in insert/search time in your graphs can be explained by the explosion of tree depth as a result of providing the binary tree builder with the worst-case input (sorted). Cache and similar effects are certainly possible but you won't see them on a logarithmic scale graph. It would have been interesting to also chart the time taken by your AVL algorithm, since it's not going to be so adversely affected by the input. But there's no visible spike in the cost of linked list ins/srch, and that too would be affected by cache misses.